# why is an error being generated when i change the engine to INNODB in Sqlyog?

Tags: database, innodb, sqlyog

I'm trying to create a database in Sqlyog and i would like to set the engine to INNODB. However when I execute the sql command to alter from MyISAM to INNODB, the following error is displayed:

```
Warning Code : 1286
Unknown storage engine 'innodb'
```

Does any of you know how to solve this problem please as I would like to use foregin keys and they are not allowed with MyISAM

thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Execute SHOW ENGINES; Check whether InnoDB engine is supported or not for your server.

Comment: no its not supported... in fact its the only one which is not supported... is there a way where i can change this in able to be supported please?

Comment: You can try removing ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 from the data directory of the installation folder. And restart the server.

Comment: MySQL seems to disable it automatically if your InnoDB log files get corrupted. When you remove them, they are recreated, allowing InnoDB to start again. So as Sathish said remove them and restart your server. And, your problem will be solved. :-)

Comment: i cant find these files in the sql folder... does this mean that they have been removed already?

Comment: Execute SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir'; which will show u the path of the folder.

Comment: i did and the path stated does not contain these log files... it only contains 3 folders and non contain these either :/

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#option_mysqld_innodb
Please refer this link and check if --skip-innodb is enabled or not.

Comment: If skip inndob line is present in my.ini/my.cnf just comment-out that line.

Comment: is this file supposed to be found in thr MySQL folder as i cant find this file anywhere

Comment: Yes. It will be in MySQL folder.

Answer (score 3):

Execute

> SHOW ENGINES;

and check whether InnoDB engine is supported or not for your server. If it is not supported then:

1) You can try removing ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 from the data directory of the installation folder. And restart the server beacuse MySQL seems to disable it automatically if your InnoDB log files get corrupted. When you remove them, they are recreated, allowing InnoDB to start again.

OR

2) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#option_mysqld_innodb refer this link and check if --skip-innodb is enabled or not.If skip inndob line is present in my.ini/my.cnf just comment-out that line.

Comment: i tried to use the second option however when i save the file its stating that it has failed and to check whether it is being used by another program or not.. ive even stopped the service... besides the mysql service... is there another one which maybe uses it?